# Can a subject complement be always replaced by a noun (phrase)?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'd like to know if there is a noun phrase meaning anything will die (disappear) eventually (not limited to life, but including other things not related to life). I know an adjective for this meaning as *mortal*. But I want to find a noun phrase with the same meaning. The purpose is to find a noun (phrase) alternative to a classic syllogism as:

```
All men are mortal.
Socrates is a man.
So Socrates is mortal.
```

Generally, we want to know if a subject complement can always be replaced by a noun (phrase).

Comment: How about "life-form"?

Comment: No, it could be non life related things. For life, I think *mortal being* is the one I am looking for.

Comment: ***mortal*** is also a noun and carries that connotation. “*Lord, what fools these mortals be!”   -A Midsummer Night’s Dream*

Comment: I want to include other creatures or even things, not limited to humans only.

Comment: How does "life-form" include "non life related things"?

Comment: Things don't disappear when they die. I, for one, am going to be mummified and placed in a giant pyramid.

Comment: Is *immortal* also applied to non life related things?

Comment: *This thing all things devours:
Birds, beasts, trees, flowers;
Gnaws iron, bites steel;
Grinds hard stones to meal;
Slays king, ruins town,
And beats high mountain down.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since everything in the world can be divided into two categories as life and substance, and all lives will die or disappear after some times as we say all lives are mortal, while substances can last for a long time (forever) as some substances are immortal, I think I have found an answer to this question as *mortal being*.

Comment: But substances don't last forever or even for a long time in some cases. If you break an ice cube you end up with smaller pieces of the same substance, but if you "break" water into oxygen and hydrogen now you have two different substances and the water is gone.

Comment: Thanks, I modified it. Also I modified the post so it becomes whether a subject complement can always be replaced by a noun (phrase)

Answer (score 0):

Something that will eventually cease to exist (whether it is organic and dies or inorganic and otherwise disappears) is [**finite**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finite):

> **1 b** : having a limited nature or existence
>   // *finite* beings

---

But whether it should be *finite beings*, *finite entities*, or *finite things* is problematic. There is no single noun that unambiguously covers both humans and baseball bats …

Answer (score 0):

As far as whether for every predicative complement (PC) there is a corresponding noun phrase (NP) which denotes exatly the things that have the property expressed by the PC, the answer is yes, this is always possible.

It is of course hard to prove a negative (that something definitely doesn't exist), and for all I know, there could be obscure counterexamples. However, **as a rule**, there is indeed such a correspondence.

Here is why. PCs are either NPs (in which case we are done: the NP that appears as PC is the required NP), or bare role NPs, or adjectives.

In the case of adjectives, one can always use the same adjective to build an NP (at least I can't think of an example where that's not possible). So *the people are **afloat*** leads to the NP *the people who are **afloat***, etc.

And in the case of bare role NPs (phrases that would be NPs if they had a determiner), such as *treasurer* in *Pat is **treasurer***, as best as I can tell, these are always count nouns (*treasurer, secretary, president,* and so on), and so one can simply use their plural form to make the required NP (e.g. *treasurers*).

**Extra comments**

1. I don't see how *mortal* could apply to non-living things. No dictionary I looked at would support such usage. The adjective you actually want is more something like ***impermanent*** or ***transient*** (see e.g. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/impermanent)).
2. We saw that to every PC there corresponds an NP denoting the objects that have the property expressed by the PC. There is, however, in general no guarantee that there is **single noun** denoting the objects that have the property expressed by the PC. It is usually hard to prove a negative, but in technical fields the absence of alternatives is more obvious. So here is one definitive example of an adjective without such corresponding single noun (i.e. without a single noun denoting exactly the things that have the property described by the adjective): ***continuous***. We can say that a function or a mapping is *continuous*, but English mathematical vocabulary definitely does not have a corresponding noun denoting just the objects that are continuous.

In your particular case, there is an archaic sense of a single noun that has the required meaning: ***creature***. According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/creature), that noun has, among others, an archaic sense whose meaning is *anything living or existing.*  Lexico gives this sample usage:

> dress, jewels, and other transitory **creatures**

I don't have a handy source for what I'm about to say, but I believe this usage has to do with the notion that apart from God, everything else is created (by God), and so everything else can in principle cease to exist. So we are all *creatures* in the sense that we are created, and thus finite. According to some (many? most?) theologies, our *souls* are not transient, and time alone will not make them cease to exist. But God could.

Comment: @MathWizard The point is that there is no noun that denotes all mathematical objects that are continuous. I've added some further clarifying text so it is clear that this is what I meant.

Comment: @MathWizard Exactly. As I state in the text, one can always construct a required NP. The only thing that doesn't necessarily exist is a single noun whose meaning is (even roughly) identitcal to the meaning of an NP constructed that way.

Comment: @MathWizard Yes, I know—both your question and your answer include NPs. In short, my own answer provides a bit more information than required by your question: I commented on both single nouns *and* on NPs. I do understand that you weren't asking about single nouns. I commented on them anyway because that seemed (to me; others are free to disagree) to be a natural thing to do.